# How to prevent text selection on focus() in chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, textselection

On Focus the text in the input box is getting selected in Chrome ,Works fine in FF .How do i get rid of that

My selector is as follows

```
$('.edit').click(function(){


$('input').focus();

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Workaround I use:

```
$('.edit').click(function(){
    $('input').focus().val($('input').val());
});​
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/prv4n/)